# Slideshow - make a jQuery Plugin from working code fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've created a little slideshow with images out of a folder with jQuery and with help from stackoverflow and other snippets.

Images are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg ... 1-b.jpg, 2-b.jpg...The special thing is, that every image-change 3 images are loaded. The first time the images in the HTML (3 images too) are replaced.

2 of the 3 new images are blurred, to have a fade from current to - blurred current - into blurred next - next. Works fine and looks really great.

Now I want to make a real jQuery plugin out of that, because I want to change the startup (image Nr.) and imageLast (here go back to startup) on every site. Well I don't know if there are problems with the logic of the original code to make a plugin. My trials failed. Please have a look.

Original working code:

```
 // slideshow ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(function() {
var pauseTime = 7000;
function slideShow(index) {
    var imagePath = "slider-team";
    var startup = 1;
    var startindex = index+startup-1;
    var index1 = startindex+1;
    var lastImage = 6;         
    var fadeTime = 700;
    var fadeTime2 = 500;
    var fadeTime3 = 1000;
    var theImage1 = new Image();
    var theImage2 = new Image();
    var theImage3 = new Image();
    var url = imagePath + "/" + startindex + ".jpg";
    var urlb = imagePath + "/" + startindex + "-b.jpg";
    var url2b = imagePath + "/" + index1 + "-b.jpg";
        $(theImage1, theImage2, theImage3).load(function () {                   

                    $(theImage1).prependTo("#slider");
                    $(theImage2).prependTo("#slider");                      
                    $(theImage3).prependTo("#slider");

        $("#slider img:last").fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
           $(this).remove();
           $("#slider img:last").fadeOut(fadeTime2, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $("#slider img:last").fadeOut(fadeTime3, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                                slideShow((index % (lastImage-startup)) + 1)
                                }, pauseTime);
            });
           }); 
           });
        });
        theImage1.src = url;
        theImage2.src = urlb;
        if(startup+index === lastImage) {
            theImage3.src = "slider/" + startup + "-b.jpg";
            } else {
            theImage3.src = url2b;
            };
     }
     $(document).ready(function() {
        // Img 1 is already showing, so we call 2
        setTimeout(function() { slideShow(2); }, pauseTime);
     });
  })();
```

Trial to make a plugin:

```
// slideshow ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (function($) {
    $.blurSlider = function(index, settings){
    var config = {
      'startup':1;
      'lastImage':17;
    };
    if(settings){$.extend(config, settings);}

    var pauseTime = 7000;
    //function slideShow(index) {
    var imagePath = "slider-opt";
    //var startup = 1;
    var startindex = index+startup-1;
    var index1 = startindex+1;
    //var lastImage = 17;         
    var fadeTime = 700;
    var fadeTime2 = 500;
    var fadeTime3 = 1000;
    var theImage1 = new Image();
    var theImage2 = new Image();
    var theImage3 = new Image();
    var url = imagePath + "/" + startindex + ".jpg";
    var urlb = imagePath + "/" + startindex + "-b.jpg";
    var url2b = imagePath + "/" + index1 + "-b.jpg";
        $(theImage1, theImage2, theImage3).load(function () {                   

                    $(theImage1).prependTo("#slider");
                    $(theImage2).prependTo("#slider");                      
                    $(theImage3).prependTo("#slider");

        $("#slider img:last").fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
           $(this).remove();
           $("#slider img:last").fadeOut(fadeTime2, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $("#slider img:last").fadeOut(fadeTime3, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                                slideShow((index % (config.lastImage-config.startup)) + 1)
                                }, pauseTime);
            });
           }); 
           });
        });
        theImage1.src = url;
        theImage2.src = urlb;
        if(config.startup+index === config.lastImage) {
            theImage3.src = "slider/" + config.startup + "-b.jpg";
            } else {
            theImage3.src = url2b;
            };
    // }

     };
      return this;
     $(document).ready(function() {
        // Img 1 is already showing, so we call 2
        setTimeout(function() { $.blurSlider(2); }, pauseTime);
     });
  })(jQuery);
```

I don't know if in plugins you need to set up the selector. Here I don't, because the selector didn't change. The call of document.ready inside the plugin is the other thing that might cause problems.

Comment: The document ready call should be outside the definition. Are you able to create a JSfiddle of this for testing?

Comment: There most likely already exists such a plugin.

Comment: @Zar: polygon? Your spell checker has a mind of its own :)

Comment: @HiTechMagic Haha! :-) That's what happens when you try to write in English using Swedish autocorrect..